# What to do with 'universe' and 'space' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

If you look at the [universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universe) and [space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) tags you'll immediately notice that except for one or two of the questions the rest either has wrong tags, are closed or else are hugely down-voted (by the way, this is a good moment to take a look and vote to close some of them).

Now, I wonder what's the best strategy to go about these tags? Personally I'd remove the *space* tag completely (because space, in its most concrete meaning is either just a mathematical or a philosophical concept. No physics in that).

As for *universe*, I am inclined to let it stay (in connection with cosmology and astrophysics).

So, what do you think we should do with them?

Comment: Also the "time" tag should be removed, in my opinion...

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... well, I think there are legitimate questions about the universe that could be tagged [universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universe) (probably along with either [cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmology) or [astrophysics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophysics), or both). There *could* even be some legitimate questions about space. ([Does anything exist in the intergalactic space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560/does-anything-exist-in-the-intergalactic-space) might be an example, but you could argue that that's an astronomy question, not really astrophysics.) But I wouldn't be opposed to getting rid of [space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space).

Most of the [space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) questions right now are either really about spacetime, or have nothing to do with space. I'll go through and retag some of them.

Comment: Thanks, David. I am also not sure about the tags; that's why I brought this up here. I'll sort out rest of the *space* questions, if you don't mind. As for the "intergalactic space"... I think *universe* will do just fine.

Comment: Although I am not sure what to do with questions that actually don't belong on this site and so don't admit any reasonable tags. Is it fine to leave them with wrong tags? E.g. [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/994/what-makes-a-space-a-real-space).

Comment: I'm fine leaving tags that we consider to be "bad" attached to those sorts of questions. It helps reinforce the idea that questions about topic X are generally inappropriate for the site.